# OxyPlot DateTimeAxis, Show Index instead of Time

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have a Oxyplot Graph in my WPF application, with LinearAxis as Y, and DateTimeAxis as X. This works fine. My question was more on the Displayed Labels in DateTimeAxis.
Instead of displaying Time, I would like to display Index. For example,

[image]

I tried following (using LabelFormatter to show index),

```
        var index = 1;
        var xAxis = new DateTimeAxis()
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
            MinorIntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours,
            IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours,
            MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.Solid,
            MajorStep = 1.0/24,  
            IntervalLength = 75,
            MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None,
            LabelFormatter = (x) => index++.ToString()

        };
```

This does display number instead of Time, but instead of beginning from 1,

- it starts at some value x (in my case in early 40s)
- and each
  time I resize the graph, the value increases (say after first resize
  it begins at 108).

Example
[image]
Is there a way i could achieve, even after resizing ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it would be easier to transform the x-axis programmatically fom time to indexes and use a linear axis for it as well?

Comment: Dearest Downvoter, kindly describe why question was downvoted ? or atleast provide a solution or some hints ?

Comment: @RolandDeschain Unfortunately thats not possible in my current scenario. I have to somehow stick to DateTime Axis.

Comment: That's second down voter who hasn't either left any hint on solution or mentioned why they felt the question is unworthy. May be am dumb and not knowing the answer that is in plain sight, but it would be great if two down voters could at least mention reason.